# undefined function cast_attachments/3

Tags: file-upload, elixir, phoenix-framework

New to Elixir and Phoenix. Tried whatever I can do.
`defmodule Countdown.Posts.Post do
        use Ecto.Schema
        import Ecto.Changeset
        schema "posts" do
            field :description, :string
            field :image, Countdown.PostUploader.Type
            field :shot, :naive_datetime
            field :title, :string
            timestamps()
        end
        @doc false
        def changeset(post, attrs) do
        post
        |> cast(attrs, [:title, :shot, :description, :image])
        |> cast_attachments(params, [:image])
        |> validate_required([:title, :shot, :description, :image])
      end
    end`

error:

> == Compilation error in file lib/countdown/posts/post.ex ==
>   ** (CompileError) lib/countdown/posts/post.ex:19: undefined function cast_attachments/3
>       (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
>       (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:677: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
>       (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're using [arc_ecto](https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto) to upload an image.

Then you might want to `use` `Arc.Ecto.Schema` to have the `cast_attachments` macro included:

```
 defmodule Countdown.Posts.Post do
   use Ecto.Schema
   use Arc.Ecto.Schema
   import Ecto.Changeset

    schema "posts" do
      field :description, :string
      field :image, Countdown.PostUploader.Type
      field :shot, :naive_datetime
      field :title, :string
      timestamps()
    end

    @doc false
    def changeset(post, attrs) do
      post
      |> cast(attrs, [:title, :shot, :description, :image])
      |> cast_attachments(params, [:image])
      |> validate_required([:title, :shot, :description, :image])
  end
end
```

Comment: then I get this error:
lib/countdown/posts/post.ex:6: undefined function schema/2

Comment: thanks. Its working. So we need Arc.Ecto to just include cast_attachment methods. Rest will be fetched from Ecto.schema. I assumed that Arc.Ecto.Schema is super set of Ecto.schema

Comment: @RadzSingh yea, me too